# Rendering Bitmap on Canvas [Java - Android]

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm doing a game on Android with a SurfaceView and a Canvas. For the player, I use 4 pics depending on the direction his walking.
Well, in order to not spend a lot of time, in the constructor I define 4 Bitmaps for each direction:

```
public void initImages(){
        right = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_right);
        right = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
        left= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_left);
        left = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
        up = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_up);
        up = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
        down = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_down);
        down = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
}
```

When I move the player I call this type of method:

```
public void right(){
        x++;
        self = right;
}
```

where `self` is the current Bitmap that I'm using.
The problem is that when I run the game, the bitmap is not changed, and I have always the same Bitmap.

I've already tried this:

```
public void right(){
        x++;
        self = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_right);
        self = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
}
```

but it cause a few problems and it is actually very slow.

What I am doing wrong? Any suggestion?

EDIT: This is the entire class code

```
public Player(Activity con, int x, int y){
    this.con = con;
    Player.x = x;
    Player.y = y;
    body = new Paint();
    life = 3;
    self = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.normal);
    self = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
    initImages();
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(self, x*size, y*size, body);
    //called in the game loop
}

public void right(){
    x++;
    self = right;
}

public void initImages(){
    right = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_right);
    right = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
    left= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_left);
    left = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
    up = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_up);
    up = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
    down = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.player_down);
    down = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(self, size, size, true);
}
```

Comment: Why are you initializing the all the variables twice in initImages() and right() ?

Comment: I was looking for a solution, the real problem is why "self = right" doesn't work

Comment: self is the Bitmap that is rendering. Tell me more about invalidate()

Comment: and it is redrawn, look at the edit

Answer (score 0):

How does your onDraw look like?

Usually you have a `Handler`, a `Runnable` looking something like

```
Runnable r = new Runnable{
    @Override
    run(){
    invalidate(); //<- tells the View its images arent right so it calls onDraw again.
    }
};
```

and a `myHandler.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);` at the end of your onDraw. FRAME_RATE is either 30 for 30fps or 15 for 60fps, but you can of course use other values.